# Why do I see R3 register in the LC-3 simulator instead of R1, as I wrote in a sample.bin file?

Tags: assembly, machine-code

Program code below:

```
1110 001 011111111 ; R1 <-- x3100 (PC+0xFF)
0101 011 011100000 ; R3 <-- 0
0101 010 010100000 ; R2 <-- 0
0001 010 010101100 ; R2 <-- 12
0000 010 000000101 ; if Z, goto x300A (PC+5)
0110 100 001000000 ; Load next value to R4
0001 011 011000100 ; Add to R3
0001 001 001100001 ; Increment R1 (pointer)
0001 010 010111111 ; Decrement R2 (counter)
0000 111 111111010 ; Goto x3004 (PC-6)
```

There is a screenshot that shows the problem I have.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2XJQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Raw Mode, with the LC-3 simulator, the first line tells it where to locate the subsequent code.  Thus, your `0xE2FF` — which you intended as an instruction — is taken as the `ORG` address, and the first instruction placed there is the first `AND` instruction (your 2nd intended instruction).

Try inserting the following as the very first line:

```
0000 000 000000000 ; ORG 0x0000
```

Or use

```
0011 000 000000000 ; ORG 0x3000
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It helped!